# How to use Chainlink with Truffle/Ganache?

Tags: truffle, chainlink

How to use Chainlink with Truffle/Ganache ***without unboxing a new app***? (I have an app already, I don't want to unbox a new one)

I'm trying to get the Chainlink price feeds working in local development using Ganache / Truffle.

How is something like accomplished?

Comment: What do you mean without unboxing a new app? Do you have a box with enables local testing with Chainlink?

Comment: There are tutorials that mention using Truffle unbox to get a boilerplate Chainlink app. I don't have any boxes personally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To work with [Chainlink price feeds](https://docs.chain.link/docs/using-chainlink-reference-contracts) in your local environment and deployment framework, you'll want to fork a blockchain.

I've included using hardhat and brownie in this answer as they have forking that comes already installed.

#### For just ganache

The easiest way is to use the forking feature.

```
ganache-cli --fork=http://infura.io/mainnet
```

When you run the client, you can fork mainnet and then just use the price feed contract addresses as normal but on your local chain.

#### For truffle

Truffle has two options:

[1. Truffle teams forking](https://www.trufflesuite.com/blog/sandbox-forking-with-truffle-teams)

[2. Write your own ganache-cli server](https://github.com/truffle-box/defi-box)

Truffle doesn't come pre-installed with a forking feature, but you can sign up for truffle teams and use a forking feature through that. Or, you could write your own server.

#### [Hardhat forking](https://hardhat.org/guides/mainnet-forking.html)

Hardhat is a truffle-like smart contract deployment and testing framework. It comes with a forking feature that forks a blockchain to it's hardhat virtual environment (similar to ganache local blockchain). In your hardhat config, you just write the following:

```
networks: {
  hardhat: {
    forking: {
      url: "https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/<key>"
    }
  }
}
```

Additionally, you can run a hardhat local chain with the command:

```
npx hardhat node --fork https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/<key>
```

#### Brownie

Brownie is a python deployment framework that also has forking. You can check out the [documentation](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/network-management.html) if you'd like to learn more.